# how to get .att("value") jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="hidden" value="#F00" name="" class="myValue">
$(document).ready(function(){
var myValue = $(".myValue").val();
console.log(myValue);
});
```

It returns "value=#F00";
It should return
    #F00; only

Comment: $(".myValue") is a class selector. please correct it will work

Answer (score 1):

There is no element with class name of `.myValue`, instead you can use these:

```js
console.log($('[name="myValue"]').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv">
  <input type="hidden" name="myValue" value="#F00">
</div>
```

or with `:hidden` pseudo selector :

```js
console.log($('.myDiv :hidden').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv">
  <input type="hidden" name="myValue" value="#F00">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are using `myValue` as class.

Where as in html it the `name` attribute. So you need to select name attribute to retrieve the value

```
var getValue = $( "input[name='myValue']" )

console.log(getValue.val());
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/sc9ubvz8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log($("input[name=myValue]").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you select element using '.' e.g. `$(".myValue")` the "`myValue`" should be a class of that element and not the name.

If you want to select using name then use: `$("[name='myValue']").val()` or    `$("input[name='myValue']").val()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var myValue = $(".myValue").val();
console.log(myValue);
});
```

It worked as it is... Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this it will work for you

```
  <input type="hidden" value="#F00" name="" class="myValue">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var myValue = $(".myValue").val();
         console.log(myValue);
       });
    </script>
```